# how to show selected option in MVC asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have this code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a id="na" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Environments <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new { environment = "" }, null)</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new {environment = "" }, null)</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new { environment = "" }, null)</li>
                // <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new { environment = "" }, null)</li>
            </ul>
```

`

I want to know how to show the selected option that user pressed on the render html

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
        $(function(){

        $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
console.log($(this).text());
       });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question that you want to display or know which Actionlink or hyperlink was clicked from those 3 li's ? 
If yes, then you can send some route values in your view

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a id="na" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Environments <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new { environment = "1" }, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new {environment = "2" }, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new { environment = "3" }, null)</li>
                    // <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports - ", "Index", "Reports", new { environment = "" },null)</li>
                </ul>
```

and then in your controller of Report Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string environment)
{
  string ClickValue = environment; //You get use Clickvalue here
}
```